# Confused over basic ODE solved two different ways producing different answers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $y'=xy+x+y+1$, I attempted to solve it in two ways. Firstly by separation of variables:
$$y'=(x+1)(y+1)$$
$$\frac{y'}{y+1}=x+1$$
$$\int \frac{dy}{y+1} = \int x+1\ dx$$
$$\implies y(x) = Ae^{\frac{x^2}{2}+x}-1$$.

However, if I use the integrating factor, I get:
$$y' + (-x-1)y = x + 1$$
$$I(x) = e^{\int -x-1\ dx} = e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}-x}$$
$$\implies y(x) = \frac{1}{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}-x}}\int e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}-x} (x+1)\ dx = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}+x}(-1)e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}-x}=-e^0=-1.$$

Clearly, this is the particular solution of $A=0$, but I was under the impression that the integrating factor was supposed to produce the *general* solution of the ODE. What's going on here?

Comment: You need to add an integration constant to the indefinite integral.

Comment: Your $I(x)$ has the Integral in the Power , where you have to include the Constant of Integration $C$ , which will then give $e^C e^{\cdots}$. You will then get the general Solution with $A=e^C$ !

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the second solution shoud be
$$ y(x) = \frac{1}{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}-x}}\int e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}-x} (x+1)\ dx+  \frac{B}{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}-x}}.$$